# List as Json encoding returns Last index value

Tags: json, flutter, dart, encoding

here i have added the value to the contactList.listChild but the the string list doesn't return all the value to the parent list it only returns the last added value. i know its a simple mistake though i couldn't figure out where am making mistake.

any suggestion would be helpful.

```
   ContactName contactList = new ContactName();

  createJson(){

    for(int index = 0; index < _contacts.length; index++){

      Contact contact = _contacts?.elementAt(index);
      List<Item> numbersList = contact.phones.toList();

      for(int i = 0; i < numbersList.length; i++ ){

        contactList.listChild = [numbersList[i].value];
      }

      contactList.name = contact.displayName;

      lisJson.add(contactList.toJson());

    }

    var data = {
      "data" : lisJson
    };

    var body = json.encode(data);
    print("$body");

  }

// here is my model class

class ContactName extends Object {

  String name;
  List<String> listChild = new List<String>();

  Map toJson() => {"name":name, "phone":listChild};
}
```

this is what am getting from this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "user1",
      "phone": [
        "8221551458"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "user2",
      "phone": [
        "1234567890"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// and the output should be something like this 

{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "user1",
      "phone": [
        "8221551458"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "user2",
      "phone": [
        "8220780548"
        "1234567890"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
contactList.listChild = [numbersList[i].value]
```

by

```
contactList.listChild.add(numbersList[i].value)
```

Your code is creating a new list on every iteration of the for statement, that's why the last element is the only one you see.

Be sure to initialize `contactList.listChild` before using it or will throw an exception when trying to add a new element.